# If $L \cdot \{\epsilon, a, b\}$ is regular, is $L$?

Tags: automata, regular-language

> Given that $L \cdot \{\epsilon, a, b\}$ is regular, is $L$ regular too? (Our alphabet is $\Sigma = \{a,b,c,d\}$

What I thought was yes, and here is why:

> If it is regular, then we know there is a finite automat such that $L(M) = L \cdot \{\epsilon, a, b\}$. Now, since it accepts that language, we know that at most there are three accepting states. One that we get to by reading the last $\epsilon$, one by reading the last $a$, and one by reading the last $b$. They can be also one state that is acheived by reading any of thee three.. etc. Now if we remove that (those) accepting states, and put the one previous to the last reading of either $a$ or $b$ or $\epsilon$, and mark them as accepting states, then we will have a finite automat that accepts $L$.

Is that correct or?

Comment: It’s not true that there must be $3$ accepting states; there could be more or fewer.

Comment: Ah, correct. But is my general approach okay?

Comment: There is no "reading the last $\epsilon$"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For suitable $A\subseteq 2\mathbb N$ we have that
$$ L=\{\,\alpha\in\{a,b\}^*:|\alpha|\notin A\,\}$$
is not regular (use the pumping lemma). But $L\cdot\{\epsilon,a,b\}=\{a,b\}^*$ is clearly regular.

Comment: What do you mean by $|a| \notin A$?

Comment: @TheNotMe: $|\alpha|$ is the length of the word $\alpha$. Hagen is saying that you can choose a set $A$ of even natural numbers so that the set of words over $\{a,b\}$ whose lengths are **not** in $A$ is not regular. But then every word over $\{a,b\}$ of odd length will be in $L$, so every word of positive even length will be $\alpha a$ or $\alpha b$ for some $\alpha\in L$, and $L\cdot\{\epsilon,a,b\}$ will be $\{a,b\}^*$. (You have to make sure that $0\notin A$, or you get only $\{a,b\}^+$.)

Comment: Oh thanks alot!